# How do I turn on gzip in Apache2?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, unix, gzip

I simply did :

```
sudo aptitude install apache2
```

And that's how my server is set up. No extra modules, no  nothing.

I'm on ubuntu jaunty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/deflate.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/
```

and restart apache

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: That's it? I don't have to do anything else? Everything should work correctly, as if nothing has changed?

Comment: or you can just do "sudo a2enmod deflate", which does the same thing.

Answer (score 14):

Debian/Ubuntu have the a2* set of scripts for managing modules and vhosts. You can use a2enmod:

```
$ sudo a2enmod deflate
Enabling module deflate.
Run '/etc/init.d/apache2 restart' to activate new configuration!
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2
 ... waiting                                                             [ OK ]
$
```

Answer (score 0):

check [this manual](http://www.howtoforge.com/apache2_mod_deflate), describes quite clearly and is for debian like systems